# Dovecot returns a hash mismatch after setup

Tags: 20.04, postfix, postgresql, dovecot

So I had a working setup with postfix and dovecot with virtual users stored in a postgresql db on an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS. I've decided to make a new setup on a VPS based on the same settings (that I followed mostly from this guide https://123qwe.com/tutorial-debian-10/) but with Ubuntu 20.04. Receiving mails works perfectly fine but I can't login with any mail client and doveadm auth test says auth failed on passdb.

I made a test account with password `test123` using `argon2` with `12345678` as salt and stored it in the db but in /var/syslog (after turning more dovecot debug logging) I get the following message:

```
ARGON2ID(test123) != '$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$c2FsdD0xMjM0NTY3OA$jppnL4/+/mHkh2kx8SHoXcv65u0yf5p2HIRDPXe93ZM'
```

But running `echo test123 | argon2 salt=12345678` (the command I used to generate the hash and store it in the db) shows the exact same hash.

I am really confused! Anybody might have an idea what's going on?

Edit forgot to mention the versions
Postfix is 3.4.13
Dovecot is 1:2.3.7.2
Postgresql is 12+214

Answer (score 0):

By generating the hash using doveadm pw -s ARGON2ID I noticed the result was slightly different than with the argon2 tool. Storing it in the database revealed a success in logging in afterwards!